# Python: create 3D array using values of another 3D array that meet a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm basically trying to take the weighted mean of a 3D dataset, but only on a filtered subset of the data, where the filter is based off of another (2D) array. The shape of the 2D data matches the first 2 dimensions of the 3D data, and is thus repeated for each slice in the 3rd dimension.

Something like:

```
import numpy as np

myarr = np.array([[[4,6,8],[9,3,2]],[[2,7,4],[3,8,6]],[[1,6,7],[7,8,3]]])
myarr2 = np.array([[7,3],[6,7],[2,6]])
weights = np.random.rand(3,2,3)

filtered = []
for k in range(len(myarr[0,0,:])):
    temp1 = myarr[:,:,k]
    temp2 = weights[:,:,k]
    filtered.append(temp1[np.where(myarr2 > 5)]*temp2[np.where(myarr2 > 5)])

average = np.array(np.sum(filtered,1)/len(filtered[0]))
```

I am concerned about efficiency here. Is it possible to vectorize this so I don't need the loop, or are there other suggestions to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most glaring efficiency issue, even the loop aside, is that `np.where(...)` is being called multiple times inside the loop, on the same condition! You can just do this a single time beforehand. Moreover, there is no need for a loop. Your operation basically equates to:

```
mask = myarr2 > 5
average = (myarr[mask] * weights[mask]).mean(axis=0)
```

There is no need for an `np.where` either.

`myarr2` is an array of shape `(i, j)` with same first two dims as `myarr` and `weight`, which have some shape `(i, j, k)`.

So if there are `n` True elements in the boolean mask `myarr2 > 5`, you can apply it on your other arrays to obtain `(n, k)` elements (taking all elements along third axis, when there is a True at a certain [i, j] position).